# Horizontal list items

Tags: html, css

So, I have attempted to create a horizontal list for use on a new website I am designing. I have attempted a number of the suggestions found online already such as setting 'float' to left and such - yet none of these have worked when it comes to fixing the problem.

```css
    ul#menuItems {
      background: none;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul#menuItems li {
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      top: 0px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    ul#menuItems li a {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: #000;
      height: 50px;
      width: auto;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="menuItems">
  <li>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="index.php">DJ Profiles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently I am unsure of what is causing this issue, how would I go about and resolve it?

Comment: see http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm

Answer (score 160, accepted):

## Updated Answer

I've noticed a lot of people are using this answer so I decided to update it a little bit. No longer including support for now-unsupported browsers.

```css
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">some item</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">another item</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: upvoted answer because it does fix the issue, but floats are lame and old! unless ur using IE7-, u should be using `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey That is a great point - I will add that as a second option - Thank you for the tips

Comment: The list collapses when the browser window is resized - is there a way to prevent that? Ideally, the list should retain its horizontal layout no matter what. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland Set a `min-width` on the `ul` element:

`#my-list{
    min-width: 780px;
}
`

Comment: Why the zoom?  Also is "*" in front of display a typo?

Comment: @RayLoveless, no, the `*` is deliberate, but probably no longer needed as IE7 is pretty much dead. In the olden days, you could hack IE7 to work by placing an asterisk in front of a directive - modern browsers would ignore the whole line, while IE would parse it, and apply the attributes.

Answer (score 15):

I guess the simple solution i found is below

```
ul{
    display:flex;
}
```

Comment: This suggestion fixed my problems! Thanks

Comment: You may want to add ```justify-content: ``` for spacing the items within.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 10):

This fiddle shows how

http://jsfiddle.net/9th7X/

```
ul, li {
    display:inline
}
```

Great references on lists and css here:

http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/

Comment: Chances are good that your issue doesn't have anything to do with Bootstrap.  It's more likely that your CSS has overrides that cause this `display:inline` directive to be ineffective.

Comment: Firefox inspect element says that the rule is enabled: https://i.imgur.com/Picq9Lr.png

Comment: Does it work in the fiddle?  If so, probably deserves its own question.

Comment: @RayLoveless have a look at caniuse.com for the ancient stuff.

Answer (score 6):

A much better way is to use `inline-block`, because you don't need to use `clear:both` at the end of your list anymore.

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">some item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">another item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul > li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Have a look at it here : http://jsfiddle.net/shahverdy/4N6Ap/

Answer (score 3):

You could also use inline blocks to avoid floating elements

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">some item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">another item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and then style as:

```
li{
    /* with fix for IE */
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    /*
    additional styles to make it look nice
    */
 }
```

that way you wont need to float anything, eliminating the need for clearfixes

Comment: I have attempted this, yet they're still not being shown horizontal - www.s4nr.com/SpecialTesting

Comment: @LoadData your menu has a width of 100px and your li's have a combined width of 128px, so the second item will drop down to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

strong tex

```css
ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
```

```html
        <ul>
            <li>bla</li>
            <li>blabla</li>
            <li>blablabla</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxpu3/1/) you can find a working example, with some more suggestions about dynamic resizing of the list.

I've used display:inline-block and a percentage padding so that the parent list can dynamically change size:

```
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 1%;
width: 30%
```

plus two more rules to remove padding for the first and last items.

```
ul#menuItems li:first-child{padding-left:0;}
ul#menuItems li:last-child{padding-right:0;}
```