# Displaying a unordered list horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I have a unordered list of images and I need to display them horizontally in a row with no margin/padding or list styling, what CSS would I use to do this?

Here is my html code:

```html
<div id="carouselContainer">
    <ul id="carousel-list">
        <li><a href="/"><img src="image.png" alt="Desc" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><img src="image.png" alt="Desc" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><img src="image.png" alt="Desc" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><img src="image.png" alt="Desc" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Horizontal list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/css-horizontal-list-items)

Answer (score 3):

Setting the float to left will make the list horizontally

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS.

```
 #carousel-list{padding:0;margin:0;}
 #carousel-list li{display:inline-block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcLoq7k3/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyahfjwe/2/)**

```
#carousel-list {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#carousel-list li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#carousel-list
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

but google is faster

Answer (score 1):

what about CSS:

```
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```