# How to bring ul list-items in horizontal rather than vertical?

Tags: html, css

I want to make menu using links which come horizontally rather than vertically

HTML code

```
<div>
        <ul>
            <li> <a id="ccs" href="#"> Home </a> </li>
            <li> <a id="ccs" href="#"> Marketing Service </a> </li>
            <li > <a id="ccs" href="#"> IT Management Service </a> </li>
            <li > <a id="ccs" href="#"> Molex Portfolio </a> </li>
            <li > <a id="ccs" href="#"> Contact US </a> </li>
            <li > <a id="ccs" href="#"> Employment Opportunities </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS Code

```
#ccs{
    background-color:#4CAF50;
    padding:20px;

    border:3px;
    color:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
```

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please research... http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp or [CSS Horizontal list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/css-horizontal-list-items?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `display:inline-block;` from `#ccs`

Then use

`li {
  display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: Thanks For your help . Your answer perfectly worked as per my requirements. I am studying css from w3schools.com and I am half way through it. I haven't studied inline-block thats why I was facing problem
Thanks for your help again!!!!