# how to show my items in horizontal in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I need show my items category in horizontally in `codeigniter`. This is my `controller` file.

```
$this->data['itemdata'] = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Printers / Accessories',
                'items' => [
                    [
                    'name' => 'Printers',
                    'group' => 'printers',
                    'images' => ['printers/canon1-printers.jpeg','printers/canon2-printers','printers/hp1-printers.jpeg','printers/hp2-printers','printers/hp3-printers','printers/hp4-printers']
                    ],
                    [
                    'name' => 'Printer Cartridges',
                    'group' => 'cartridges',
                    'images' => ['cartridges/canon-cartridges.jpeg', 'cartridges/hp-cartridges.jpeg']
                    ],
```

this is view file.

```
<?php foreach ($item['items'] as $key => $value): ?>
    <li>
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" data-fancybox="<?php echo $value['group']; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo @$value['images'][0]; ?>">
           <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I need controller items view horizontally in my view file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Horizontal list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/css-horizontal-list-items)

Comment: This aint related to codeigniter not php, is just a css issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline;` to list your items horizontally

```
<li style="display: inline;">
```

or

Add a **class** name to your **li** tag and add style in your style-sheet

```
<li class="horizontalItem">
```

In your style-sheet

```
.horizontalItem{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: it is not arrange properly

Comment: I need horizontally this one **<?php echo $value['name']; ?>**