# Difference between <nav> tag and the <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have used the < div > tag to create a navigation menu bar but it only displays in a vertical fashion. However, I then changed the < div > tag into a < nav > tag, but still receive the same results in a vertical orientation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items)

Comment: what's wrong with `li { display: inline }`?

Comment: Inline either `ul` or `li`, not `nav`.

Comment: if you had a look on w3schools you could find this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black ;  you also need to set li components float:left;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `ul` add `display: flex;`

```css
nav {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #262626;
  overflow: hidden;

}
li a {
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```