# How to space out list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigationbar

I am unable to get my `nav` to sit the way I like, the header is fine but `ul` just won't sit right.

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h2>hackeryou</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Bootcamp</li>
      <li>Part-Time</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I expect the `h2` to stay left but I want everything else to move be more spaced out on the right.

Comment: What exactly you're looking for? How you want the the nav to appear?

Comment: there are many ways to accomplish this, with padding, flex properties, margins, :before, :after, etc etc. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `justify-content: space-between` for `nav ul` as the whole `nav` is already shifted to the right. Just add a `margin` as required to `nav ul li` - see demo below:

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px; /* ADJUST THIS */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h2>hackeryou</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Bootcamp</li>
      <li>Part-Time</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```