# Horizontally growing lists, inter-element separators, no pre-element bullets, no vertical alignment. How?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

If you check out a navigation box at the bottom of a Wikipedia article (here's an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Web_browsers)),
you'll notice they do something distinctive with their lists:

1. Lists grow horizontally, but wrap vertically when hitting the end of their containing element.
2. Bullets go *between* elements, not *before* elements.
3. Lists elements are not forced into columns (they don't have to align vertically).

I like the way these lists look, but I'm having a hard time finding ways to exactly replicate them.  I can find similar solutions to [put list elements into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns) or just [have horizontal growth without inter-element separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items).  I've used my browser's code inspector to look at the html for the wikipedia navs, but the style sheets get a bit crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig up the style sheet for the `hlist` class [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Snippets/Horizontal_lists).  Works like a charm.  I'll provide an example. Credit to wiki user Edokter for coming up with this style.

```css
header, footer {
  text-align: center;
}

/*Grow horizontally, don't put bullet marks.*/
ul.hlist li {
  display: inline;
}

/* Put a bullet after every element.*/
ul.hlist li:after {
  content: " • "
}

/*Unless it's the last element.  Then put nothing.*/
ul.hlist li:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
  <h1>
  Full Name
  </h1>
  <ul class="hlist">
    <li>
    email@address.com
    </li>
    <li>
    123-456-7890
    </li>
    <li>
    personal-website.com
    </li>
  </ul>
  </header>
  <p>
  Pretend this is lorem ipsum.
  Just a ton of lorem ipsum.
  Going on for several lines.
  Just total nonsense.
  Nonsense a million times.
  Not meant to be read at all.
  Just a bunch of vaguely Latin sounds
  all garbled together.
  </p>
  <footer>
  <ul class="hlist">
    <li>
      Pretend
    </li>
    <li>
      These
    </li>
    <li>
      Are
    </li>
    <li>
      Nav
    </li>
    <li>
      Options
    </li>
    <li>
      Or Something
    </li>
  </ul>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```